# How to correctly incorporate JavaScript into html?

Tags: javascript, html

I know very little about code, but I am looking to "fork" [this creation](https://codepen.io/jhealey5/pen/JRGgVr) by John Healey anyway. It is written in JavaScript, but I was hoping to incorporate it into html so that it could easily open in a browser.

Once I figured out the necessary tags for html, I tried putting the above code in between both header and body (at different times) but neither seemed to work. I have tried switching out the image (which I plan on doing later anyway) in case there was something wrong with it but that didn't fix it either. I am wondering if this is a processing power issue as I am using a shitty Acer 2-in-1 running an old version of Windows 10. After furious Googling, this is what I've come up with (I'm so sorry for putting this whole thing here):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="application/javascript">
var doc = document,
    win = window,
    body = doc.body;

var ww = win.innerWidth,
    wh = win.innerHeight;

var c = doc.createElement('canvas'),
    ctx = c.getContext('2d');

var half_PI = Math.PI / 2,
    two_PI = Math.PI * 2,
    ease = 0.01;


var k = {
    offsetRotation: 0,
    offsetScale: .8,
    offsetX: 0,
    offsetY: 0,
    radius: 1100,
    slices: 16,
    zoom: 1.5
};

body.appendChild(c);
c.width = k.radius * 2;
c.height = k.radius * 2;

var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504532472068-9ae844337da7?ixlib=rb0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=6e76ebffebd8e3c65985875554e36f35&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1334&q=80'; 
var fill = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat'); 

var scale, step, cx;

scale = k.zoom * (k.radius / Math.min(img.width, img.height));
step = two_PI / k.slices;
cx = img.width / 2;

function draw(){

    ctx.fillStyle = fill;

    for (var i = 0; i <= k.slices; i++) {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(k.radius, k.radius);
        ctx.rotate(i * step);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(-0.5, -0.5);
        ctx.arc(0, 0, k.radius, step * -0.51, step * 0.51);
        ctx.rotate(half_PI);
        ctx.scale(scale, scale);
        ctx.scale([ -1,1 ][i % 2], 1);
        ctx.translate(k.offsetX - cx, k.offsetY);
        ctx.rotate(k.offsetRotation);
        ctx.scale(k.offsetScale, k.offsetScale); 
        ctx.fill();

        ctx.restore();

    }

} 


var tx = k.offsetX;
var ty = k.offsetY;
var tr = k.offsetRotation;


win.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove, false);
function mousemove(e){
    var cx, cy, dx, dy, hx, hy;
    cx = ww / 2;
    cy = wh / 2;
    dx = e.pageX / ww;
    dy = e.pageY / wh;
    hx = dx - 0.1;
    hy = dy - 0.1;
    tx = hx * k.radius * -.8;
    ty = hy * k.radius * .8;
}

c.style.position = 'fixed';
c.style.marginLeft = -k.radius + 'px';
c.style.marginTop = -k.radius + 'px'; 
c.style.left = '50%';
c.style.top = '50%';

function update() {
    tr -= 0.002; 

    k.offsetX += (tx - k.offsetX) * ease;
    k.offsetY += (ty - k.offsetY) * ease;
    k.offsetRotation += (tr - k.offsetRotation) * ease; 

    draw(); 

    requestAnimationFrame(update);
};
update();
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

What I am hoping for is an interactive kaleidoscope that can open in a browser but all I get is a blank Chrome tab. Any help is appreciated as I think I have figured out as much as I can on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some issue in your code, almost related to the asincronous loading of the image, and the variable scope.

Take a look at the [snippet below](https://jsfiddle.net/InferOn/acu3eqz6/).

```
<html>
  <head> </head>
  <body>
    <script type="application/javascript">
      var doc = document,
        win = window;

      var body = doc.body;

      var ww = win.innerWidth,
        wh = win.innerHeight;

      var c = doc.createElement("canvas"),
        ctx = c.getContext("2d");

      var half_PI = Math.PI / 2,
        two_PI = Math.PI * 2,
        ease = 0.01;

      var k = {
        offsetRotation: 0,
        offsetScale: 0.8,
        offsetX: 0,
        offsetY: 0,
        radius: 1100,
        slices: 16,
        zoom: 1.5
      };

      body.appendChild(c);
      c.width = k.radius * 2;
      c.height = k.radius * 2;

      var tx = k.offsetX;
      var ty = k.offsetY;
      var tr = k.offsetRotation;

      win.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemove, false);
      function mousemove(e) {
        var cx, cy, dx, dy, hx, hy;
        cx = ww / 2;
        cy = wh / 2;
        dx = e.pageX / ww;
        dy = e.pageY / wh;
        hx = dx - 0.1;
        hy = dy - 0.1;
        tx = hx * k.radius * -0.8;
        ty = hy * k.radius * 0.8;
      }

      c.style.position = "fixed";
      c.style.marginLeft = -k.radius + "px";
      c.style.marginTop = -k.radius + "px";
      c.style.left = "50%";
      c.style.top = "50%";

      function update(fill) {
        tr -= 0.002;

        k.offsetX += (tx - k.offsetX) * ease;
        k.offsetY += (ty - k.offsetY) * ease;
        k.offsetRotation += (tr - k.offsetRotation) * ease;

        draw(fill);

        requestAnimationFrame(update);
      }

      function draw(fill) {
        ctx.fillStyle = fill;

        for (var i = 0; i <= k.slices; i++) {
          ctx.save();
          ctx.translate(k.radius, k.radius);
          ctx.rotate(i * step);
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(-0.5, -0.5);
          ctx.arc(0, 0, k.radius, step * -0.51, step * 0.51);
          ctx.rotate(half_PI);
          ctx.scale(scale, scale);
          ctx.scale([-1, 1][i % 2], 1);
          ctx.translate(k.offsetX - cx, k.offsetY);
          ctx.rotate(k.offsetRotation);
          ctx.scale(k.offsetScale, k.offsetScale);
          ctx.fill();

          ctx.restore();
        }
      }
      var scale, step, cx;

      var img = new Image();
      img.onload = () => {
        scale = k.zoom * (k.radius / Math.min(img.width, img.height));
        step = two_PI / k.slices;
        cx = img.width / 2;
        update(ctx.createPattern(img, "repeat"));
      };

      img.src =
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504532472068-9ae844337da7?ixlib=rb0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=6e76ebffebd8e3c65985875554e36f35&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1334&q=80";
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

All the best.

Comment: I tried this one on two different computers, and it worked best. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are calling `createPattern` on your `<img>` before it has finished loading the image. When you do this, `createPattern` returns `null`. As shown in this sample, you must wait until the image's `onload` event is fired to call `createPattern`.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="application/javascript">
    var doc = document,
      win = window,
      body = doc.body;

    var ww = win.innerWidth,
      wh = win.innerHeight;

    var c = doc.createElement('canvas'),
      ctx = c.getContext('2d');

    var half_PI = Math.PI / 2,
      two_PI = Math.PI * 2,
      ease = 0.01;


    var k = {
      offsetRotation: 0,
      offsetScale: .8,
      offsetX: 0,
      offsetY: 0,
      radius: 1100,
      slices: 16,
      zoom: 1.5
    };

    body.appendChild(c);
    c.width = k.radius * 2;
    c.height = k.radius * 2;

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504532472068-9ae844337da7?ixlib=rb0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=6e76ebffebd8e3c65985875554e36f35&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1334&q=80';
    var fill1 = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
    console.log("fill1", fill1);
    img.onload = () => {
      var fill2 = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
      console.log("fill2", fill2);
    }
    
    // ... code afterwards omitted for brevity
  </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `text/javascript` is obsolete.

Comment: @AngelPolitis You're right. I'm astounded that I didn't know that, but I also found the real solution

Answer (score 0):

The problem i found in your code was , you wrote script before the body tag of html and it was not able to find it . 
I made some changes in your code , you can take a look [here](https://js.do/code/333512)

Comment: sorry about the alert and comment . Forgot to remove it . It should work fine now .

Answer (score 0):

move your `script` code inside the `<body>` tag

like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="application/javascript">
var doc = document,
    win = window,
    body = doc.body;

var ww = win.innerWidth,
    wh = win.innerHeight;

var c = doc.createElement('canvas'),
    ctx = c.getContext('2d');

var half_PI = Math.PI / 2,
    two_PI = Math.PI * 2,
    ease = 0.01;


var k = {
    offsetRotation: 0,
    offsetScale: .8,
    offsetX: 0,
    offsetY: 0,
    radius: 1100,
    slices: 16,
    zoom: 1.5
};

body.appendChild(c);
c.width = k.radius * 2;
c.height = k.radius * 2;

var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504532472068-9ae844337da7?ixlib=rb0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=6e76ebffebd8e3c65985875554e36f35&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1334&q=80'; 
var fill = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat'); 

var scale, step, cx;

scale = k.zoom * (k.radius / Math.min(img.width, img.height));
step = two_PI / k.slices;
cx = img.width / 2;

function draw(){

    ctx.fillStyle = fill;

    for (var i = 0; i <= k.slices; i++) {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(k.radius, k.radius);
        ctx.rotate(i * step);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(-0.5, -0.5);
        ctx.arc(0, 0, k.radius, step * -0.51, step * 0.51);
        ctx.rotate(half_PI);
        ctx.scale(scale, scale);
        ctx.scale([ -1,1 ][i % 2], 1);
        ctx.translate(k.offsetX - cx, k.offsetY);
        ctx.rotate(k.offsetRotation);
        ctx.scale(k.offsetScale, k.offsetScale); 
        ctx.fill();

        ctx.restore();

    }

} 


var tx = k.offsetX;
var ty = k.offsetY;
var tr = k.offsetRotation;


win.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove, false);
function mousemove(e){
    var cx, cy, dx, dy, hx, hy;
    cx = ww / 2;
    cy = wh / 2;
    dx = e.pageX / ww;
    dy = e.pageY / wh;
    hx = dx - 0.1;
    hy = dy - 0.1;
    tx = hx * k.radius * -.8;
    ty = hy * k.radius * .8;
}

c.style.position = 'fixed';
c.style.marginLeft = -k.radius + 'px';
c.style.marginTop = -k.radius + 'px'; 
c.style.left = '50%';
c.style.top = '50%';

function update() {
    tr -= 0.002; 

    k.offsetX += (tx - k.offsetX) * ease;
    k.offsetY += (ty - k.offsetY) * ease;
    k.offsetRotation += (tr - k.offsetRotation) * ease; 

    draw(); 

    requestAnimationFrame(update);
};
update();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```